# Own RubyGems: internal paths

Tags: ruby, path, rubygems

I'm actually writing my own RubyGem.

How do I get the path to the RubyGem, i.e. for requiring?

```
require "./mygeminternally.rb"
# => the path (actually "./") must be the path to the internals of the gem while it is being compiled
```

Is it just `Dir.getwd`? I need a method that brings me the path to the gem so I can use internal templates. Be aware that templates or configuration files have to be accessed while the gem is compiled, is this so easily possible like picking the right path?

Yours,

Joern

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear.  Are you trying to load from **within** the gem?  If so, perhaps [this guide](http://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/#loading-code) will help?  If you're trying to load your gem from client-code, you can just build and install it locally: `gem build <gemname.gemspec>` then `gem install gemname-version.gem` then just require it as you would any published gem.  Or am i misunderstanding your question?

Comment: yeah that guide was it. Can you post it as an answer, so I can apply it as the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a gem you should always use paths relative to your `lib` dir and never try to evaluate absolute paths because this can cause problems in some edge cases.

When I say `lib` I actually mean one of the directories added to `require_paths` in the `.gemspec` file, but in almost all cases this is set to just `['lib']`.

This is all described in detail in the [RubyGems Guide](http://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/#loading-code) (as mentioned by @an4rco in his comment -- give him an upvote).